# R Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

Tags: r, sample

I am trying take a stratified sample of audio files within specific time intervals of a lunar week over the course of a two year data set. This code was running fine a week or so ago, I realised many of the files were however no audible due to rain drowning out the sound of anything else. I then removed the files that were corrupted in this way and the sample no longer runs, giving the error message above. The entire code is very long so I will give a portion of it, however if you need more of the code provided I can do so. There are 215046 obs pre sample so it should not give the error

```
#create a new column as an individual ID for each moonphase
sampdat3$MP<-1

#create the IDs
for (i in 2:length(sampdat3$MP)){  #if the moonphase is the same as the last moonphase, MP is the same. If its different to the last moonphase, add 1
  if(sampdat3$Moonphase[i]==sampdat3$Moonphase[i-1]){sampdat3$MP[i]<-sampdat3$MP[i-1]}else{
    sampdat3$MP[i]<-sampdat3$MP[i-1]+1
  }
  
  
}


# Remove rain files (total rain >=4)

sampdat4<-sampdat3[ ! sampdat3$Total_Rain_Q2.1 %in% c(4,5,6,7,8), ]

#create a time object for each row at 6pm of the relevant data
dn2<-paste0(sampdat4$Date, "_", "18:00")
dn2<-gsub(" ", "", dn2)

sampdat4$cut1<-as.POSIXct(dn2, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M", tz="America/Sao_Paulo")            

#10pm
dn2<-paste0(sampdat4$Date, "_", "22:00")
dn2<-gsub(" ", "", dn2)

sampdat4$cut2<-as.POSIXct(dn2, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M", tz="America/Sao_Paulo")            

#just before midnight -couldn't get to format properly at midnight
dn2<-paste0(sampdat4$Date, "_", "23:59:59")
dn2<-gsub(" ", "", dn2)

sampdat4$cut3a<-as.POSIXct(dn2, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M", tz="America/Sao_Paulo")            

#just after
dn2<-paste0(sampdat4$Date, "_", "00:00:01")
dn2<-gsub(" ", "", dn2)

sampdat4$cut3b<-as.POSIXct(dn2, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M", tz="America/Sao_Paulo")            


#02:00
dn2<-paste0(sampdat4$Date, "_", "02:00")
dn2<-gsub(" ", "", dn2)

sampdat4$cut4<-as.POSIXct(dn2, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M", tz="America/Sao_Paulo")            

#05:00
dn2<-paste0(sampdat4$Date, "_", "05:00")
dn2<-gsub(" ", "", dn2)

sampdat4$cut5<-as.POSIXct(dn2, format = "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M", tz="America/Sao_Paulo")            



#create time intervals for each row(file)
sampdat4$int1<-as.interval(sampdat4$cut1, sampdat4$cut2) #between 18:00-22:00
sampdat4$int2<-as.interval(sampdat4$cut2, sampdat4$cut3a) #22:00-23:59:59
sampdat4$int3<-as.interval(sampdat4$cut3b, sampdat4$cut4) #00:01:00-02:00
sampdat4$int4<-as.interval(sampdat4$cut4, sampdat4$cut5) #02:00-05:00



#add a second to start times so none start at 00:00:00 -bit of a bodge
sampdat4$dTime<-sampdat4$dTime+1

#create columns for each row to give logical values as to whether the file is within the interval
sampdat4$smp1<-sampdat4$dTime%within%sampdat4$int1
sampdat4$smp2<-sampdat4$dTime%within%sampdat4$int2
sampdat4$smp3<-sampdat4$dTime%within%sampdat4$int3
sampdat4$smp4<-sampdat4$dTime%within%sampdat4$int4

#set seed so random sampling is replicable
set.seed(1157)

#get an index of the moonphases
ind<-unique(sampdat4$MP)

#create storage list
smp_fin<-list()

rm(s1, s2, s3, s4, smp_fin, smp2, subs)

i=1
for(i in 1:length(ind)){
  subs<-sampdat4[sampdat4$MP==i,] #subsample to moonphase[i]
  s1<-subs[subs$smp1,] #subsample to only the files within the first interval
  s1<-s1[sample(1:length(s1$Date), 14),] #sample those files 14 times
  s2<-subs[subs$smp2,]
  s2<-s2[sample(1:length(s2$Date), 4),] #didn't want to split to 3 and, 4, so just increases sampling to 4 and 4
  s3<-subs[subs$smp3,]
  s3<-s3[sample(1:length(s3$Date), 4),]
  s4<-subs[subs$smp4,]
  s4<-s4[sample(1:length(s4$Date), 8),] #increased here to keep samples equal
  smp_fin[[i]]<-rbind(s1,s2,s3,s4)
}
```

Error message comes from the s1:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
> cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

There are 215046 obs pre-sample so it should not give the error  - any help appreciated

** EDIT **
I have tried using `replace = TRUE` instead, this gives me a far too large sample around 3 times the size it should be

Comment: Are you able to reproduce with a dataset from a package such as `datasets` or `ggplot2::diamonds`? The premise that `sample(n, size=14, replace=TRUE)` gives other than 14 samples is a little difficult to take.

Comment: Side note: `1:length(x)` works only as long as `x` is longer than 0 elements. Once it's zero, this *fails*, since `1:0` returns a vector of length 2, not length 0 as one might expect. Consider replacing `1:length(x)` with `seq_along(x)`. Note that even if you make this change within `sample`, trying to sample a zero-length vector will fail, though you can do `sample(nrow(s1), size=min(nrow(s1), 14))`.

Comment: Try inputting a list instead of a column in the function, you won't get error